# Where does the "Objective" in Objective-C come from?

Tags: objective-c, programming-languages

I want to know why Objective-C is called "objective". (Other languages, such as C++ and Java are also object oriented, yet they don't carry the title "Objective".)

Comment: Search google...................

Comment: Then why is C++ *not* called "Objective C" and Java *not* "Objective Java"? Why things are called the way they are called is mostly trivia...

Comment: In this day and age, Google is man's good friend. Try it...

Comment: they why XHTML is called XHTML not as HTML++(like c and c++).

Comment: @aravindhanarvi, for XMHTL, it was the adoption of a more strict XML-like approach to HTML document structure I guess, that inspired the rename...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply because Objective-C is a superset of C, which adds object-oriented features (based on Smalltalk).  The very first version was called "OOPC" for Object-Oriented Pre-Compiler, which was literally a precompiler for C which added objects and message-passing.

- [History of Objective-C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective_c#History)

Answer (score 4):

To quote Wiki, here is:

> Cox began writing a pre-processor for C to add some of the capabilities of Smalltalk. He soon had a working implementation of an object-oriented extension to the C language, which he called "OOPC" for Object-Oriented Pre-Compiler

Check [this, it might shed more light](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C)...